# Disable touchpad Tap to Click without software

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I can disable the touchpad "Tap to Click" using the Alps Dell Touchpad tray icon.  But that is just one more thing running constantly.  If I remove `Apoint` from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\` I lose the icon, but also the disabling of touch to click.

Is there any way to disable touch to click without using the Touchpad software running constantly?

Comment: So I assume there's no such setting in the Windows' Control Panel mouse or trackpad preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can set the tray icon not to appear. This solves your problems, assuming your problems were a)wanting to disable Tap to Click and b)not wanting to have to look at the tray icon.

I can understand not wanting a bunch of stuff running all the time, but if the stuff is relatively small and serves a purpose, I say let it run.

Comment: And it's the thing computers are good at: running software ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately mine seems to be having difficulty with that and I am trying to reduce as many variables as possible.